# If JWT-Token is stolen

Tags: jwt

For instance, if an attacker gets ahold of your JWT token , they could start sending requests to the server identifying themselves as you and do things like make service changes, user account updates, etc. Once an attacker has your JWT it is game over.

So how we can secure our routes with JWT token if token is stolen ?

Comment: You can't. Until the token expires, whoever has it is authorised - that's what "bearer token" means.

Comment: Tokens expire after a period of time, like 2 hours

Comment: @jonrsharpe Unless there's a server-side revocation list, of course.

Comment: But if some  hacker got the token so they can change username and password.

Comment: That's why password resets generally require you to reconfirm your old password.

Comment: Ok thank you got it

Answer (score 4):

Basically you're right, if an attacker steals an access token (it doesn't have to be a JWT), then she can do anything that that token allows, and for as long as the token is valid. There are some steps you can take to mitigate the problem or do some damage control:

1. Keep short expiration times of tokens. If the token lives for only 2 or 5 minutes then the amount of data an attacker can steal will be limited.
2. Limit scopes of tokens. You shouldn't have tokens with which you can do everything. If you issue tokens which allow the user only to read their data, then even if someone steals it, they won't be able to change the password.
3. Use proof-of-possession tokens. These are tokens which are tied to the client which received them in the first place. When someone steals such a token, they won't be able to access the API, unless they also have access to a proof of possession (which can be a certificate). These are examples of POP tokens: [Certificate-bound access tokens](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-certificate-bound-access-token/) and [DPoP tokens](https://curity.io/resources/learn/dpop-overview/)
4. You can use something which at Curity we called a [Token Handler pattern](https://curity.io/resources/learn/the-token-handler-pattern/) to hide your tokens from the browser and fallback to good old sessions. This makes your tokens much harder to be stolen.

If you're working with JWTs, have a look also at an article I wrote about [security best practices when handling JWTs](https://curity.io/resources/learn/jwt-best-practices/).

Comment: Thank you so much